# Where is the identity map from the usual topology on the reals to the discrete topology continuous?

Tags: general-topology

At what points in $\mathbb{R}$ is the identity map
$$i\colon (\mathbb{R},\zeta)\to(\mathbb{R},\zeta')$$ continuous?
Where $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers, $\zeta$ is the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\zeta'$ is the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I know that the identity  map 'i' defined in  my question is not continuous but does there exist any point in R at which the map i is continuous?

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be continuous at a point?

Comment: A function f:(X,ζ)→(Y,ζ') is said to be continuous at a point p∈X if for any open set V of Y containing f(p) ∃ an open set U of X containing p such that

Comment: f(U) contained in V

Comment: f(U) contained in V

Comment: Yes, for 1∈R, {1} is an open set of discrete topological space but it's preimage which is {1} is not open in usual topological space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the definition of continuity at a point, for $p \in \mathbb{R}$, can you find an open set $V$ containing $p$ whose preimage (which happens to also be $V$) is not open?

Comment: Yes, for 1∈R, {1} is an open set of discrete topological space but it's preimage which is {1} is not open in usual topological space.

Comment: Now extend that argument to every point $p \in \mathbb{R}$ and you're done.

Comment: Yes I got it ,thanks